# Why am I getting error code C2276 while using void functions?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Movie
{
private:
    ifstream inMovie;       //private member variables

    void openFile();
    void testFile();
    void readFile();

public:
    Movie();                //constructor
    void driver()
    {
        openFile();

    };          
};

void Movie::openFile()
{
    ifstream inMovie;
    inMovie.open("SciFiMovies.txt");
    testFile();
    readFile();
}

void Movie::testFile()
{
    ifstream inMovie;
    if (!inMovie.open)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open the file.";
        exit(1);
    }
}

void Movie::readFile()
{
    ifstream inMovie;
    string file;
        while (!inMovie.eof)
        {
            getline(inMovie, file);
            cout << file;
        }
}

int main()
{
    Movie movObj;
    movObj.driver();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting an error code? Using the ! typically works for me when I want to test if a file fails to open or when I read a file. Also, the teacher requires that we use several different void functions, which is why the program may look a little weird (with several functions to accomplish a simple task). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you getting compiler errors? Please post the exact text of the compiler messages.

Comment: Remember that not everyone here has Visual Studio or is sufficiently familiar with Visual Studio to know what the error codes are. Side note: Wen parsing in the error messages, prefer to use the full build output from the Output tab rather than the abbreviated version in the Error list Tab. Quite often the extra information on the Output tab alone is enough to riddle out the problem without outside assistance. Fr me the error list is useful as an overview. As a problem-solving tool, it sucks.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
if (!inMovie.open)
```

and

```
while (!inMovie.eof)
```

Both `open` and `eof` are functions, not data members. You need to include `()` on them, like so:

```
if (!inMovie.open())
```

and

```
while (!inMovie.eof())
```

Also, some suggested reading: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Also also, not related to the error, but since you redefine `inMovie` in each function, you will end up with both of those checks always being `false`. Remove the redefinition, and rely on the class member variable.

Comment: Also there's an errant `ifstream` local variable in each member function, that'll break the program